# Hide/show button for all images in a database

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to place every image that I have retrieved from a database into a collapsible `<div>`. I would like to use jQuery as I have a general idea as to how to accomplish this with that library. My problem is that the page will have a varying amount of images for each user, and each `<div>` needs to be unique so that one image can be hidden but another shown.

My code to echo the images out looks like this:

```
<td><div id="img<? echo $url['url_key']; ?>"><img src="<? echo $url['qr_code']; ?>" /></div></td>
```

Which will output something like this:

```
<div id="img3"><img src="" /></div>
```

My jQuery to show and hide an image will have to look something like this I think:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.some_unique_identifier').click(function() {
        $('#load_div_that_corrolates').fadeToggle("slow")
    });
```

My question is how can I use the unique identifier that I am echoing out from PHP, in my jQuery code so that each unique code has its own block of jQuery. Or if there is a better way to make a collapsible set of images. Also, I set my `<div>` to have a

```
style="display: none"
```

property, and this makes it so that my table's borders are not displayed as well. Is there a different value that I can set to display where this wouldn't happen?

Comment: add an id tag to the image as well <img id="image1" src="..." alt="..."/>

Comment: what is the user clicking to kick off the fade?  does each image have a button? Or do you want to click where the image should be?

Comment: eh, if only i wasn't feeling so lazy, i'd make you an answer. Look up "$.ajax" and how to use `$('#staticParent').on('event', 'selector', callback(e){})`. This will be much faster than preloading all the images and require only about ... 12 or so lines of code all together using jQuery. PHP block will be even easier. Just get GET/POST data on the ajax call for the image id and look it up and send it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TO ACCOMPLISH THIS BY LETTING USER CLICK DIV**

add a class to the img div

```
<div id="img3" class="imgContainer"><img src="" /></div>
```

when they click on the image div:

```
$('.imgContainer').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('img').fadeToggle('slow');
};
```

css styling:

```
.imgContainer {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**TO ACCOMPLISH THIS BY CREATING A BUTTON FOR EACH IMAGE**

on each loop also create a button with the KEY in it:

```
<button onclick="ShowImage('<? echo $url['url_key']; ?>')">toggle image</button>
```

then similar function to show image with param passed from button:

```
function ShowImage(imgKey) {
    $('#img' + imgKey + ' img').fadeToggle('slow');
}
```

Comment: can somebody explain the function ShowImage(imgKey) {
    $('#img' + imgKey + ' img').fadeToggle('slow');
} bit to me? I can seem to get the images to toggle, but I have checked the debugger and no errors are coming through.

Comment: put an alert or console.log in the method to spit out the imgKey